# How do I segregate values in one column into different columns?

Tags: r

I have the following entry in a column

```
flags
***AP***
***AP***
***A****
***AP***
***A****
***AP***
***AP***
***AP***
```

I need to create two column with values as follows

```
flag1 flag2
1     1
1     1
1     0
1     1
1     0
1     1
1     1
1     1
```

where 1 in flag1 corresponds to A is present, similarly 1 in flag2 corresponds to P is present. 
How do I remove * and seperate A and P to two different columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check for existence (i.e. partial match) of `A` and `P` in column `flags`, you could do:

```
cbind(df, sapply(c("A", "P"), grepl, df$flags))
#     flags    A     P
#1 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
#2 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
#3 ***A**** TRUE FALSE
#4 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
#5 ***A**** TRUE FALSE
#6 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
#7 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
#8 ***AP*** TRUE  TRUE
```

`TRUE` and `FALSE` can be used the same way as `1` and `0` though the columns are of class `logical`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mtabulate` with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1, mtabulate(str_extract_all(df1$flags, "[A-Z]")))
#     flags A P
#1 ***AP*** 1 1
#2 ***AP*** 1 1
#3 ***A**** 1 0
#4 ***AP*** 1 1
#5 ***A**** 1 0
#6 ***AP*** 1 1
#7 ***AP*** 1 1
#8 ***AP*** 1 1
```